# Express routes to create new JSON entry in mongo collection work, but not when I use axios to send the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, axios

I'm trying to create a course registration system using a form to send student information to a database. I created Express routes to create new entries in a mongo collection by post request, and it works fine when I test it with Postman and hardcoding the JSON I want to submit into the route. But when I created an HTML form with javascript that uses axios to send the same JSON to the post, something goes wrong. It successfully passes the data to the route, but something happens where it ends up stopping at some point in the code and runs twice, throwing an error. When I try to get all data from the database after, the entries I posted show up, meaning it was successfully entered but the problem is still something I want to work out.

This is the route I created

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const data = require("../data");
const studentData = data.students;
const courseData = data.courses;

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  /* new students added by post request in the JSON form
    {
        "userName": "testUser",
        "hashedPass": "testPass",
        "profile": {
            "lastName": "testLast",
            "firstName": "testFirst",
            "studentId": 12345678,
            "year": 2,
            "credits": 0
        }
    }
  */
  try {
    const sData = req.body;
    const newStudent = await studentData.create(sData.userName,
      sData.hashedPass, sData.profile.lastName, sData.profile.firstName,
      sData.profile.studentId, sData.profile.year, sData.profile.credits);
    res.status(200).json(newStudent);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400).json({ error: "post /students" });
  }
});
```

And this is the function to create a new student

```
const mongoCollections = require("./mongoCollections");
const students = mongoCollections.students;
const uuid = require("node-uuid");

const create = async (user, pwd, last, first, studentId, year, credits) =>{
    const studentCollection = await students();
    const id = uuid.v4();
    if (!user || typeof(user) !== "string") throw "You must provide a username";
    if (!pwd || typeof(pwd) !== "string") throw "You must provide a password";
    if (!last || typeof(last) !== "string") throw "You must provide a last name for your student";
    if (!first || typeof(first) !== "string") throw "You must provide a first name for your student";
    if (!studentId || typeof(studentId) !== "number") throw "You must provide a student ID";
    if (!year || typeof(year) !== "number") throw "You must provide a year";
    if(credits !== 0){
      if (!credits || typeof(credits) !== "number") throw "You must provide number of completed credits";
    }

    const newstudent = {
      _id: id,
      userName: user,
      hashedPass: pwd,
      profile: {
        _id: id,
        lastName: last,
        firstName: first,
        studentId: studentId,
        year: year,
        credits: credits,
        finishedCourses: [],
        currentCourses: [],
        holds: false
      }
    };

    const insertInfo = await studentCollection.insertOne(newstudent);
    if (insertInfo.insertedCount === 0) console.log("Could not add student");
    const newId = insertInfo.insertedId;

    const student = await get(newId);
    return student;
  };
```

This all works fine when I send the JSON via Postman or set sData = the object I want to pass. But I created a simple HTML page with forms to submit the data from the client, but when I submit the form something strange happens. It sends the object to the route and the route receives it properly, meaning if I console.log(sData) at that point it will print the information I gave it. But then it stops running at the line
`const studentCollection = await students();`
and seemingly runs the post route again, but this time with an empty object. At that point it continues and runs through the rest of the code, and finishes but still appears to add the correct data to the collection, but the browser changes to a blank page with the error "{"error":"post /students"}" from my route. This is the HTML I'm using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getForm(){
        axios.get('/students');
      }
      function submitform(){
        axios.post('/students',
          {
            "userName": "testUser",
            "hashedPass": "tesPass",
            "profile": {
                "lastName": "testLast",
                "firstName": "testFirst",
                "studentId": 12345678,
                "year": 2,
                "credits": 0
            }
          }
        );
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="/students">
      <button type="submit" onclick="submitform()">submit</button>
    </form>
    <form method="get" action="/students">
      <button type="submit" onclick="getForm()">submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

If it helps, this is my index.js from /routes

```
const studentRoutes = require("./students");
const courseRoutes = require("./courses");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const constructorMethod = app => {
  app.use("/students", studentRoutes);
  app.use("/courses", courseRoutes);
  app.use("*", (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).json({ error: "Not found" });
  });
};

constructorMethod(app);
module.exports = constructorMethod;
```

and this is my main app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const configRoutes = require("./routes");
const path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html"));
});

configRoutes(app);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("We've now got a server!");
  console.log("Your routes will be running on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

Sorry if any of this is ignorant, I'm new to requests.
Any help would be great.
I'm running this all on localhost

**Update:**
I figured out that trying to post several times through the HTML form changes the issue slightly. It passes all of the data to the route, which creates a new student and runs all the code without issue. Then *after completion*, it seemingly runs again with an empty object, stopping when it reaches
`const studentCollection = await students();`
again. It still throws the same "{"error":"post /students"}" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div>
      <button onclick="submitform()">submit</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button  onclick="getForm()">submit</button>
    </div>
```

You don't need `form` tag, All operation is performed `onclick`,

---

**Why? Runs twice**
The javascript `submitform` function is calling POST api.
Also `<form action="POST" ...` called POST api